# VNC - Extend Display - Multiple Displays (Local and Remote)

Tags: vnc

I have a project at work where we initially thought a remote HMI display would suffice for our application. The remote HMI display would connect to the industrial PC using VNC. The PC is running Windows 7 Professional.

We have since realized that we need both a local display and the remote HMI display. Each display would be running a separate application, hence the need to 'extend' the screen over multiple displays. Each operator would be interacting with one application (of course they would have to take turns).

VNC does not appear to support extending the display (for instance I know RealVNC does not).

Can anybody recommend a solution to this problem? I am attaching a diagram to help visualize my problem.

The remote HMI is no more that 50 ft away from the industrial PC.

[image]